# Text between Bibliography title and content using multibib package

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I want to write some text between Bibliography title and content.

I tried to solve with [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197061) but it doesnot work with multibib package.
Thanks.

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ main, B , A ] }
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: clean1

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\bibpreface}[1]{\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\list}{#1\list}{}{}}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\newcommand{\ReferenceDocuments}{\rl{مستندات مرجع}}
\newcommand{\RelevantDocumentation}{\rl{مستندات ذیربط}}
\newcites{A,B}{\ReferenceDocuments%
,
\RelevantDocumentation}
\begin{document}
یک استناد به مستندات مرجع
 \cite{bb} 
 یک استناد به مستندات ذیربط
  \citeA{aa}
  یک استناد به مراجع اصلی
 \citeA{cc}
 یک استناد دیگر 
 \citeB{dd}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\rl{مراجع}}
\bibpreface{مقداری متن قبل از محتویات\\}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fa}
\bibliography{lit}

\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{lit}         

\bibliographystyleB{plain}
\bibliographyB{lit}          

\end{document}
```

And `lit.bib`:

```
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@ARTICLE{bb,
  AUTHOR =  {واحدی, مصطفی},
  TITLE =  {درختان پوشای کمینه دورنگی مسطح},
  JOURNAL =  {مجله فارسی نمونه},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}

@ARTICLE{dd,
  AUTHOR =  {بهبودی‌فام, حسین},
  TITLE =  {یک عنوان درست و درمون},
  JOURNAL =  {مجله فارسی نمونه},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}

@ARTICLE{cc,
  AUTHOR =  {بهبودی, احمد},
  TITLE =  {یک عنوان درست و درمون},
  JOURNAL =  {مجله فارسی نمونه},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using the "internals" of biblatex :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{xepersian}
% \settextfont{XB Niloofar}

% bibliography
\usepackage[natbib = true,         % true allows usage of citet, citep etc. commands
    style = authoryear,             % numeric, % trad-plain: use old bibtex plain style
    backend = biber,                %
    hyperref = true,                % 
    giveninits = true,              % first names are reduced to initials
    maxbibnames = 8, maxcitenames = 2, %
    uniquename = init, 
    uniquelist = minyear, 
    doi = false, url = false, isbn = false, eprint = false] % supress all id numbers
    {biblatex} %
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

% categories
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{published}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{conf}

% add papers to categories
\addtocategory{published}{aa}
\addtocategory{published}{dd}
\addtocategory{conf}{bb}
\addtocategory{conf}{cc}

% 
\defbibfilter{pub}{category=published}
\defbibfilter{conf}{category=conf}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}

    \defbibnote{A}{During the course of this thesis my research has contributed to the following publications:}
    \defbibnote{B}{Conference papers}

    \printbibliography[
        title = {Peer-reviewed journals},
        heading=subbibliography,
        filter = pub,
        prenote = A
        ]
    \printbibliography[
        title = {Conference contributions},
        heading=subbibliography,
        filter = conf,
        prenote = B
    ]
\end{document}
```

You have to compile this using biber instead of bibtex, preferably by `latexmk` which also takes care of compiling the document as often as necessary (and you don't have to care about how to call biber).
the command is simply `latexmk -pdf -xelatex <yourfile>`

I am sorry but I had to alter the bibliography as I lack the persian fonts:

```
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title A},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@ARTICLE{bb,
  AUTHOR =  {Author, B.},
  TITLE =  {Title B},
  JOURNAL =  {Journal B},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}

@ARTICLE{dd,
  AUTHOR =  {Author, C.},
  TITLE =  {Title C},
  JOURNAL =  {Journal C},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}

@ARTICLE{cc,
  AUTHOR =  {Author, D.},
  TITLE =  {Title D},
  JOURNAL =  {Journal D},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}
```

The output: 
[image]

---

Edit: Using bibtex and multibib (note this feels like a cruel hack, and probably is...):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{xepersian}
% \settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{A,B}
{{BibTitle A\newline\vspace{2ex}\newline\mdseries\normalsize Description text for this bibliography A},% 
 {BibTitle B\newline\vspace{2ex}\newline\mdseries\normalsize Description text for this bibliography B}%
}

\begin{document}

    \nociteA{aa,cc}
    \bibliographystyleA{plain}
    \bibliographyA{lit}         

    \nociteB{bb,dd}
    \bibliographystyleB{plain}
    \bibliographyB{lit}
\end{document}
```

You can play around with the amount of vertical distance added between the heading and the text. 
I did however find no solution in teh multibib manual. It seems that there are only headings intended, no introductory text.
The output (only fpr Bib A as the other one is set to a new page in report class):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to use bibtex.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (an more lightweight in my opinion) is to remove headers with this technique: [Using multibib without an extra title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344079/using-multibib-without-an-extra-title/344088#344088)

Then manually add titles wherever appropriate.